# How to get image metadata from ACF gallery images?

Tags: timber

I wanted to display image metadata of images from a gallery added with Advanced Custom Fields, is that possible?
So far, I've tried this (and a few other things too which didn't work either):

**front-page.php**

```
<?php
/**

The front page template file
*/
$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = Timber::query_post();
$context['post'] = $post;
Timber::render( 'home.twig', $context );
```

**home.twig**

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
  {% for image in post.get_field('gallery') %}

    {{ post.wp_get_attachment_metadata(TimberImage(image).id)   [image_metadata][aperture] }}


  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks for your answer, I hope you can help me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the meta data that you want should be available when converting to a TimberImage object so....

```
 {% for image in TimberImage(post.get_field('gallery')) %}

   {{ image|print_r }}

{% endfor %}
```

The `print_r` filter will output all the values on the object. That said, if you specifically want the array that WP normally the "fix" for your code would likely be...

```
{% for image in post.get_field('gallery') %}

    {{ function('wp_get_attachment_metadata', TimberImage(image).id). image_meta.aperture }}

{% endfor %}
```

I say "likely" because the above is untested — give it a shot and let me know!

Comment: Hey Jared, thanks for your quick answer!  
It almost worked! The image metadata gets saved in the array "image_meta" for some reason, so I had to replace that and it worked perfectly fine.  

`{% for image in post.get_field('gallery') %}  

    {{ function('wp_get_attachment_metadata', TimberImage(image).id).image_meta.aperture }}  

{% endfor %}`

Comment: Awesome! I edited my answer to match the corrected code for future searchers